# React form using Apollo & GraphQL does not trigger onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, antd

I can't seem to get `onSubmit` to trigger. Can anyone spot what's the issue here? I'm using Ant Design, but I don't think that's the issue.

*Note: Currently, the GraphQL mutation below (via Apollo) does get sent to the back-end properly. Removing `onClick` in the `Button` does trigger `onSubmit`, but the GraphQL query does not get sent.*

Update: I haven't found a solution but I found that if I remove this line `if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>`, then `onSubmit` gets triggered.

```js
import React from 'react'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo'
import { Form, Input, Button, message } from 'antd'

import { __log } from '../utils/log.js'

const { TextArea } = Input

const ADD_MENTAL_MODEL_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation AddMentalModel($mentalModelText: String!, $thoughts: [String!]){
    addMentalModel(text: $mentalModelText, thoughts: $thoughts) {
      text
      id
    }
  }
`

class MentalModelForm extends React.Component {
  // constructor(props){
  //   super(props)
  //   this.handleOnSubmit = this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this)
  // }

  handleOnSubmit = e => {
    console.log('handleOnSubmit IS EXECUTED!!!!!')
    e.preventDefault()
    debugger
  }

  _hasErrors = (fieldsError) => {
    return Object.keys(fieldsError).some(field => fieldsError[field])
  }

  render(){
    const { getFieldDecorator, isFieldTouched, getFieldError, getFieldValue, getFieldsError } = this.props.form
    return(
        <Form onSubmit={ e => this.handleOnSubmit(e)}>
          {/*
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
          */}
          <Form.Item label='Mental Model'>
          {
            getFieldDecorator(
              'mentalModel',
              {
                rules: [{required: false, whitespace: false, message: 'Missing or too short of a mental model'}]
              }
              )(<TextArea />)
          }
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label='Thought'>
          {
            getFieldDecorator(
              'thought',
              {
                rules: [{required: false, whitespace: false, message: 'Must add a thought'}]
              }
              )(<Input />)
          }
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Mutation
              mutation={ADD_MENTAL_MODEL_MUTATION}
              variables={
                {
                  mentalModelText: getFieldValue('mentalModel'),
                  thoughts: [getFieldValue('thought')],
                }
              }
            >
            {
              (mutation, {loading, error, data}) => {
                if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>
                return(
                    <Button
                      type='primary'
                      htmlType='submit'
                      onClick={mutation}
                      disabled={this._hasErrors(getFieldsError())}
                    >
                      Add new mental model
                    </Button>
                  )
              }
            }
            </Mutation>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      )
  } // render
} // class

export default Form.create({name: 'mentalmodel_hoc'})(MentalModelForm)
```

Comment: try removing the onClickEvent, and comment the result

Comment: @MateusMartins removing `onClick` does trigger `onSubmit`, but the GraphQL request does not get sent to back-end. Right now in the code above, it does get sent

Comment: try sending the GraphQL request on the submit event, if it works, let me place an answer to you accept :)

Answer (score -3):

I think that the `Button` type should be **submit** instead of **primary**

```
<Button
   type='submit'
   onClick={mutation}
   disabled={this._hasErrors(getFieldsError())}
   >
   Add new mental model
</Button>
```

Comment: Check ant-design and htmlType is the correct prop for it.